# How to block a message using WH_GETMESSAGE hook?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

In the `CBTProc` hook, there's: return 0 to `allow` the msg, 1 to `deny`.

What about the `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook? How I could 'block' a message from being executed?

In this ***example***:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(_In_ int nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    MSG* pMsg = (MSG*)lParam;

    if ((pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN) && (wParam == PM_REMOVE))
    {

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g->getmsgproc, nCode, wParam, lParam);

}
```

When the code gets inside of the block `if ((pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)`, how i could deny it from executing the `WM_KEYDOWN` msg?

Do I need to replace `pMsg->message` with something else or what?

Inside of both `return CallNextHookEx(...` the first parameter must be `nullptr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about the `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook? How I could 'block' a message from being executed?

You can't *block* the message.  Once all hook procedures in the chain have exited, the message is then passed to the original caller of `(Get|Peek)Message()`.  There is no option to avoid that.

> Do I need to replace `pMsg->message` with something else or what?

Yes, you can *modify* the message. For instance, you could set its `message` field to `WM_NULL` so the caller will effectively ignore it.

> Inside of both `return CallNextHookEx(...` the first parameter must be `nullptr`?

It doesn't really matter what you set it to. In very old versions of Windows (Win9x/ME), it had to be set to the actual `HHOOK`, but that hasn't been true for a very long. Since NT4/Win2K, the parameter is completely ignored.  So yes, setting it to `nullptr` is fine.